# bcp format file and -c switch out

Tags: linux, unix, sap-ase, bcp

I am trying to use `bcp` to extract records from a Sybase ASE database and write them to a file.  I need to exclude two of the fields in the database, so I'm trying to use a format `.fmt` file.

This is my bcp:

```
bcp Rdevdb..TBL_XFER out out1.txt -S$serv -U$user -P$pass -fbcp.fmt -c -t\|
```

I need the | char to be the delimiter.

1. When I use the `-c` switch, it seems like it's ignoring the format file all together, is this true?
2. When I use neither the `-n` or the `-c` switch (to tell it what format, native or char) it seems to create the file using native format, for when I open it in my text editor it forces it into a hex editor... is this the case?
3. when I include the `-c`, and in the format file I remove the two fields that I do not want, it brings all the db fields into the file, that's why I'm thinking it'd ignoring the .fmt file.
4. If I remove the `-c` switch, and run it with the two fields not included into the .fmt file, I get this error: `Incorrect host-column number found in bcp format-file.`
5. What combination of switches and what do I include in the .fmt file in order to get my `bcp` command to bringing me the results I want?

Here's a portion of the `.fmt` file. There are no spaces in any of the table field names (this does not include field 1 or field 2, as those are the ones I do not want in the file).

```
10.0
147
3   SYBCHAR 2   6   "|" 3   COVERAGE_CODE
4   SYBCHAR 2   6   "|" 4   DEPT
5   SYBCHAR 2   8   "|" 5   ORG
6   SYBCHAR 2   8   "|" 6   DIV
7   SYBCHAR 2   8   "|" 7   DISTRIBUTE
...
```

There are 147 fields in the table, though when I include all the fields in the .fmt file, there are a total of 149 with the first two lines that designate the version and the field number.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: keep it simple. Does it work if you leave in the first 2 fields? ELSE as a possible solution to your problem, my recollection is that even though you getting fields 3->n, you have to number the fmt file to tell it how to handle the data you're getting, so you need to number 1->(n-2). This means doing a select `f3, f4, f5, ... from tableX` and those will go through your .fmt file as col1, col2, .... Good luck.

Comment: It works if I use the -c switch, and it writes all the fields to the file (not using the fmt file).  But I don't know how to use the -c and not get the 2 fields I don't want.

Comment: it works if I use the -f switch and use the format file, but it writes it out as hex, not text. And if I remove the two fields, it gives me the error. I will try renumbering the fields in the format file... but it seems -f and -c are mutually exclusive. If I use -f it writes it out as hex. If I use -f and -c it ignores the -f and writes it at text and doesn't use the .fmt file.

Comment: I did read your original post. My questions were not meant to revisit what you have tried, but to give you some ideas for new things AND approaches to try/consider. I really think the fmt file has to begin with a column #'d 1, not 3 as your example, but it's 6 yrs since I did any of this, so it may have changed. I'll try to see if I can find a code from a case where I reordered or eliminated columns. Finally, consider updating your question with a useful edit of the exact error message/s you're getting .Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can create a view of the table with only the columns(or even rows) you are interested in, and then use bcp against the view.  It seems likely that you are transferring data to a new repository, so you will probably want to stick with using -c as character bcp's are more sharable than native files.

I have not used the -f flag, so I can't really speak to making it work that way.